# Ajax modal form validation and submit

Tags: codeigniter, validation, modal-dialog

I am new to MVC and currently working on a basic website setup. I am trying to have a modal window open where one can input some data and then press submit to submit it back to the database.

Using CodeIgniter and [this Jquery Modal](http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/) (doesn't necessary have to be this one thou).
Again I am very new to MVC so having some trouble visualizing the flow of data.

The modal opens correctly, but I'm trying to display the validation/errors in the same modal without opening a new window. What would I place near `echo("error-ajax");`, opening a view seems to result in opening a new window.

View -- Opens Modal:

`...

<a href="<?php echo site_url("bondform/view_form"); ?>" rel="modal:open" class="fa fa-plus"></a>

...`

View -- Actual Form:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>
    <h3>New</h3>
    <p>
        <label>ID: <input class="pull-right" type="text" name="idnumber" value="<?php echo set_value('idnumber'); ?>" size="9"/></label>
    </p>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                async: false,
                url: "<?php echo site_url("bondform/save_form"); ?>",
                success: function(){alert('Succes');},
                error: function(){alert('Error');}
            });     
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class Bondform extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $config = array(
               array(
                     'field'   => 'idnumber',
                     'label'   => 'Id Number',
                     'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[9]|max_length[9]|xss_clean'
                  )
            );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config); 
    }


    public function view_form()
    {
        $this->load->view('bond/form');
    }

    public function save_form()
    {       
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
            {
            echo("error-ajax"); //placeholder, debug
            }
            else
            {
            echo("error-noajax"); //placeholder, debug
            }
        }
        else
        {
        echo("succes-close"); //placeholder, debug
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, move your ajax function from the modal view to the view that opens it, then you can control the contents of the modal without losing your form view.

Opens Modal:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("bondform/view_form"); ?>" rel="modal:open" class="fa fa-plus"></a>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('body').on('submit', 'form', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url("bondform/save_form"); ?>",
                data: $(this).serialize();
                success: function(response){ $('#form_container').html(response); alert('Succes');},
                error: function(){alert('Error');}
            });     
        });
    });
</script>
```

Actual Form:

```
<div id="form_container">
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('bondform/save_form'); ?>
    <h3>New</h3>
    <p>
        <label>ID: <input class="pull-right" type="text" name="idnumber" value="<?php echo set_value('idnumber'); ?>" size="9"/></label>
    </p>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, this should get me started.